# Photoelectric effect in the context of double-slit interference

Tags: double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

When sufficiently high frequency light hits a metal surface it emits electrons. Now what will happen if the light is coming through two slits and forming an interference pattern similar to the double-slit experiment on the metal surface? Will the metal surface emit electrons or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will emit electrons according to where photons in the interference pattern hit.

Answer (score -1):

Bright spots in the pattern are where almost all photons hit, dark spots in the pattern are where almost no photons hit.  The emission will occur in the bright areas.

In double slit interference the classical explanations implied photons were hitting in the dark areas but cancelling each other out (which is a violation of conservation of energy). The modern understanding is the photon wave function which has highly probable paths (causing bright areas) that the photons follow.  A requirement of a the photon path is that its length is a multiple of its wavelength.

Comment: Will you please elaborate it? The photons are acting like waves here - they are forming an interference pattern on the metal surface. How can waves eject out electrons?

Comment: @WhiteMilkybar The answer is correct. What happens between the emission and the absorption (on the screen) may be described from different people in different way, it is unprovable. To calculate the fringes you use the interference picture. But in a closer view it is obvious that the photons get deflected from the edges and are concentrated in the bright areas. No annihilation of two photons in the dark area.

Comment: @WhiteMilkybar - The term 'interference' is historical and misleading but it is still taught today in high school and in early university courses.  The interference explanation does work mathematically in many situations (double slit approximation, thin film interference).  Ultimately it falls short as in single photon experiments where we realize there are no photons or no energy in the dark areas.   The interference explanation is convenient and as well was the norm in the early days of physics .... early 1900s.  Interference violates conservation of energy for photons.

Comment: You are posting the ***exact same answer*** for a whole bunch of different questions, independent of what was actually asked.

Comment: @PeterShor - The term 'interference' is historical and misleading but it is still taught today in high school and in early university courses. The interference explanation does work mathematically in many situations (double slit approximation, thin film interference). Ultimately it falls short as in single photon experiments where we realize there are no photons or no energy in the dark areas. The interference explanation is convenient and as well was the norm in the early days of physics .... early 1900s. Interference violates conservation of energy for photons.

Comment: Just like for electrons, the wave can be interpreted as giving the probability that a photon is detected. The wave interferes, diffract, refracts. Interference does _not_ violate any conservation law.

Comment: @my2cts What is taught at MIT for example is "The total instantaneous electric field E at the point P on the screen is equal to the vector sum of the two sources:E =E1 + E2 ."  They do not add probability waves for the DS experiment in first year, that would likely be done at the PhD level.  This classical approach works quite well to explain DS patterns and thin films.  The probability wave for a photon (called photon wave function) is a difficult concept and the boundary conditions are required to calculate the probable paths, it is not as simple as saying the probability waves interfere.

Comment: The probability to detect a photon at a specific position by a sensor based on the electric dipole transition, as most of them are, is proportional to $|E|^2 $ by Fermi's golden rule.

Comment: @my2cts Fermi's rule is about electronic transition, in the DS experiment we have scattering from a screen, not transition.  The photon wave function is probabilistic in determining the photons path likelihood, detection is another probability function as you point out.  Classically 2 photons "interfering" (i.e. arriving at the same place out of phase)  would be undetectable (i.e. dark) and their energy has disappeared.  In reality 2 photons arriving out of phase will scatter and eventually will separate. Dark areas in the pattern have no photons to begin with.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Also scattering from a screen is electric dipole interaction and is ruled ultimately by Fermi's golden rule. The probability is proportional to incident light intensity, as I stated before. No energy is lost as I stated before. This is my final comment.